# Cual seria la forma de hacer el *ngFor en angular 5

Tags: angularjs-2.0, angular4

estoy con una gran duda, como podria mostrar datos de la siguiente manera[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

a partir del siguiente array:

```js
peliculas = [
        {
            "pelicula": "Batman v. Superman",
            "director": "Zack Snider",
            "anio": "2016",
            "autor":
                [
                    {
                        "usuario": {
                            "nombre":"Mario 1",
                            "pais":"Canada"
                        }
                        
                    },
                    {
                        "usuario": {
                            "nombre":"Mario 2",
                            "pais":"USA"
                        }
                    }
                ]
        },
        {
            "pelicula": "La verdad duele",
            "director": "Will Smith",
            "anio": "2015",
            "autor":
                [
                    {
                        "usuario": {
                            "nombre":"Juan 1",
                            "pais":"Canada"
                        }
                        
                    },
                    {
                        "usuario": {
                            "nombre":"Juan 2",
                            "pais":"USA"
                        }
                    }
                ]
        }
];
```

estoy Utilizando Angular 4

Comment: Estaría bien que antes de preguntar hicieras “el tour” https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour Además, deberías poner el código que has hecho para mostrar los datos así. La comunidad te ayudará a mejorarlo o a solucionar errores; pero tienes que intentarl tú.

Comment: Tienes algo echo que no te funciona (HTML / .ts)? Convertiste ese JSon a un array de objetos? Así puedo responderte mejor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te paso un ejemplo de cómo fue que llegué a plasmarlo del lado del Front End, utilizando el mismo arreglo que muestras en tu pregunta

```
<div *ngFor="let item of peliculas">
  <p>{{item.anio}}</p>
  <p>{{item.director}}</p>
  <p>{{item.pelicula}}</p>
  <div *ngFor="let autor of item['autor']">
    <p>{{autor['usuario'].nombre}}</p>
    <p>{{autor['usuario'].pais}}</p>
  </div>
  <hr>
</div>
```

El diseño que le quieras dar, depende de ti, espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu ayuda, es lo que buscaba